# What are the difference between "shred" and "crumb"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

> [crumb](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/crumb?q=crumb)(n) a very small piece of food, especially of bread or cake,
>   that has fallen off a larger piece
>
> *She stood up and brushed the crumbs from her sweater.*

---

> [shred](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shred_2) [usually plural] a small thin piece that has been torn or
>   cut from something synonym scrap
>
> *shreds of paper*
>
> *His jacket had been torn to shreds by the barbed wire.*
>
> *Cut the orange peel into thin shreds.*

can I say "**shreds of food**" or "**crumbs of paper**"?

What are the difference between "**shred**" and "**crumb**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Crumbs" are the small, randomly shaped pieces of food that break off and are left behind. You don't get "crumbs" of paper.

A "shred" in the context of a small piece of something is a thin *strip* shape. That's why paper is referred to as having been "shredded", because it is normally torn, or cut into long, thin strips ("cross-cut shredders" are machines which cut into small pieces instead of strips, but as they are a *kind* of shredder, they maintain the name).

Small pieces of food are not usually long, thin strips, so "shred" isn't really the right word. You *can* have shreds of food, but they are normally *deliberately made* - for example, "shredded chicken" is a bit like pulled pork - it is made into strands that go with the grain of the meat. Also, When you use a kitchen tool to get zest from citrus fruit it normally comes off in small strips - a popular brand of marmalade that contains these is called 'Golden Shred'.

Comment: As the definition says, crumbs come from baked food that _crumbles_ (bread, cookies etc.), not meat or vegetables.